# How do you convert an entire folder of Python GUI's to a single executable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a bunch of .py GUI's and all of them are interconnected with one another with one of the GUI's acting as the 'Main Menu'. I am wondering if there is a way to compile all of them into a singe .EXE file or would I have to compile them one by one.

Comment: What tool are you using to convert them? Is there a particular thing you've tried so far that isn't working as expected, and can you be more specific?

Comment: What is a ".py GUI" in the first place? Are you using some kind of UI library - if so which?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I tried pyinstaller thus far, and it seems that it can only do conversions one at a time. Furthermore, I've been having issues with the tool itself.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The '.py GUI' that you are confused about is a GUI made with PyQT5 via QtDesigner.